# Find the shortest route using osmnx

Tags: python, shortest-path, osmnx

I want to find the shortest path between several points with the help of osmnx. I use the following code. But its output is only one point.
Does anyone know why?

```
import osmnx as ox

place_name = "Hamedan"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')
#graph_proj = ox.projection.project_graph(graph, to_crs='epsg:32639')

lats = [34.84008, 34.81894, 34.81746, 34.78828, 34.77877, 34.76029, 34.77038, 34.79837, 34.80043, 34.80108]
lngs = [48.54952, 48.54635, 48.51784, 48.50858, 48.51648, 48.53305, 48.50420, 48.51442, 48.50549, 48.48361]
point_list = [(lng, lat) for lng, lat in zip(lats, lngs)]

nearest_nodes = [ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph, geographic_coordinates[0], geographic_coordinates[1],  return_dist=False) for geographic_coordinates in point_list]

routes = [ox.distance.shortest_path(graph,nearest_nodes[i], nearest_nodes[i+1], weight='length', cpus=1) for i in range(len(nearest_nodes)-1)]

fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_graph_routes(graph,routes,
    ax=None,
    figsize=(8, 8),
    bgcolor="#111111",
    node_color="w",
    node_size=15,
    node_alpha=None,
    node_edgecolor="none",
    node_zorder=1,
    edge_color="#999999",
    edge_linewidth=1,
    edge_alpha=None,
    show=True,
    close=False,
    save=False,
    filepath=None,
    dpi=300,
    bbox=None)
```

Comment: You projected your graph, but you're passing unprojected lat-long coordinates into the nearest nodes search.

Comment: Thanks for your free package.
Because new versions have arrived and the names have changed, I can not find the code needed for what you said.
please guide me.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Just don't project your graph.

Comment: I edited the question, but the output is still just a dot.But if I use "distance.get_nearest_node", the output will be correct.

Comment: Your longitudes and latitudes are swapped in the list comprehension with the zip.

Comment: OSMNX has memory management issues, even smallest osm files cause huge utilization in memory. You are better off converting pbf files into csv using https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing2 and creating the graph yourself, in a disk based dictionary perhaps. Then Djikstra can handle the rest.